# Line 14 of my JavaScript(<script> inside HTML) code will not run automatically, It will only run in the chrome developer console manually

Tags: javascript, html

Line 14 of my JavaScript (`<script>` inside HTML) code will not run automatically. It will only run in the chrome developer console manually.

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<center
><div id="preloader"><iframe src="preloader.html" height="500" width="800"></iframe></div>
</center>
<center>

<script>
$("#navbar").load("nav_bar.html"); 
var el = document.getElementById("preloader");
var newEl = document.createElement('div');
newEl.innerHTML = '<div id="raze2"></div>';
setTimeout(function(){
el.parentNode.replaceChild(newEl, el);
}, 5200);
$("#raze2").load("flashmath2.github.io/Play%20Raze%202%20Unblocked%20Game%20online%20-%20Unblocked%20Games.html");
</script>
```

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: I need to know what changes I need to make to make line 14 run.

Comment: There are no line numbers, so please point, what exactly doesn't work? Please edit your post, to provide more details, what you want to do

Comment: I don't see your jQuery `.ready` function or the like. By the way there's no need to use JavaScript for what you could have just done in the HTML. Why are you using `<center>` tags? That `timeout` takes `5200` milliseconds, but your `$('#raze2').load()` is called before that takes place, so the Element would be undefined.

Comment: Thank you StackSlave, my problem was fixed by adding a delay to $('#raze2').load().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want, you can try this one:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<center
><div id="preloader"><iframe src="preloader.html" height="500" width="800"></iframe></div>
</center>
<center> 

<script>
    $("#navbar").load("nav_bar.html"); 
    var el = document.getElementById("preloader");
    var newEl = document.createElement('div');
    newEl.innerHTML = '<div id="raze2"></div>';
    setTimeout(function(){
        el.parentNode.replaceChild(newEl, el);
        var filePath = "flashmath2.github.io/Play%20Raze%202%20Unblocked%20Game%20online%20-%20Unblocked%20Games.html"
        $(el).find("#raze2").load(filePath);
    }, 5200);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<center
><div id="preloader"><iframe src="preloader.html" height="500" width="800"></iframe></div>
</center>
<center>

<script>
$("#navbar").load("nav_bar.html"); 
var el = document.getElementById("preloader");
var newEl = document.createElement('div');
newEl.innerHTML = '<div id="raze2"></div>';
setTimeout(function(){
el.parentNode.replaceChild(newEl, el);
}, 5200);
setTimeout(function(){
$("#raze2").load("/Play%20Raze%202%20Unblocked%20Game%20online%20-%20Unblocked%20Games.html");
}, 5200);
</script>
```